# How to store text of tag "a" of a div in an arrray

Tags: css, node.js, express, web-scraping

I'm working on API, which extracts data from a web site.
and the website is like - >

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<a class="item">text1</a>
<a class="item">text2</a>
<a class="item">text3</a>
<a class="item">text4</a>
<a class="item">text5</a>
</div>
```

I want to store all text in an object
like {"item1":"text1","item2":"text2"......};
here is what I'm doing

```
var prediction = $('#mainContainer > item');
console.log(prediction);
```

output

```
<a class="item">text1</a><a class="item">text2</a><a class="item">text3</a>....
```

**How do I do it ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object and then populate it with an each

```
values = {};
$('#mainContainer a.item').each((i,x) => values['item'+(i+1)] = $(x).text())
```